# Cypress - hover on an element inside iframe and get text of the hovered element

Tags: iframe, automation, cypress, ui-automation

I want to automate a scenario from the [www.moneycontrol.com](http://www.moneycontrol.com) website.
On the home page, there is a section called "Market Action", where we get some values when hovered on the graph. Like this:
[Hovered Maximum Value from Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ml2Oq.jpg)

The graph is located inside an iframe, and needs to be hovered on the maximum value always. After that, we need to fetch the hovered value, and verify it with the Market Action table header.

It need to be done using cypress only. I am able to go inside the iframe, but not sure why it is not clicking/hovering on the graph. My code is like:

```js
static getLatestValueByHoveringOnGraph = (): void => {
    HomePage.getMarketActionIframeBody()
      .find(".highcharts-series>path:first-child")
      .click("topRight")
      .trigger("mouseover");
  };

  private static getMarketActionIframeBody() {
    return cy
      .get("iframe[title='Indices Chart']")
      .its("0.contentDocument")
      .should("exist")
      .its("body")
      .should("not.be.undefined")
      .then(cy.wrap);
  }
```

I tried many ways since hours, but not getting a solution. Hope someone is able to solve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: An easier way would be to get the prices from the API response if they have a Public API.

Comment: Can't use API as hover feature needs to be validated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moveover try focus Like:

```
static getLatestValueByHoveringOnGraph = (): void => {
    HomePage.getMarketActionIframeBody()
      .find(".highcharts-series>path:first-child")
      .click("topRight")
      .trigger('focus');
  };
```

Or may be check this out https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events